# How to fix WindowsFormsHost display in windows 8 and windows server

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, windowsformshost

I am using WindowsFormsHost to host a winform control in my WPF application, but problem is, it is not displaying the view when i run my application on windows 8 or windows server OS however when i am running on windows 10 OS it is correctly displaying the view and the background work is working fine from this control in all OS just does not displaying the view in windows 8 and server.

I tried to make dlls copy local to true, installing developer pack framework and installing .NET Core 3.0 Preview 5.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host =
       new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();

     if (Browser != null)
                host.Child = Browser;
            // Add the interop host control to the Grid


            TextBox txt = new TextBox();

            txt.Text = "helllooo";
            txt.Name = "txtNumber";
            txt.Width = 4000;
            txt.Height = 2000;
          //  host.Child = txt;

            this.br2.Children.Add(host);
```

I expect this to display view in all OS like windows 8/7/server.

Note: this browser object is cefsharp chromiumwebbrowser winforms control, i don't want to use cefsharp wpf according to the requirements so please don't advice me to use cefsharp wpf

Comment: Do all of the machines you tested with have the same .NET Framework versions installed?

Comment: yes, all machines have same versions

Comment: Problem could the browser. Have you tried to display that browser in a test WinForms app (i.e. without `WindowsFormsHost`) on all machines? This is a test you could do to nail down the problem.

Comment: Not only browser but it does not display the textbox as well. i commented the textbox addition so anyone can see that i have added too.

Comment: For the `TextBox`, are you sure that it is a WinForms `TextBox` that you added to the `WindowsFormsHost`? From the code you posted, it is impossible to tell.

Comment: Yes, i have used namespaces of winforms obviously.

Comment: No one is reading the question, i said it works fine on windows 10 but not on windows 8